# How to append a list items child element (image element) if its sibling (input:checkbox) is checked, when another button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery, and I'm trying to create a game that allows users to check 3 images in a list of ten images. When the user clicks the button at the bottom of the list, I would like to append the checked images into a separate unordered list(I already have created).

```
<ul id="imageNinpputList">
        <li><image src="pics/hammer.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
        <li><image src="pics/hardhat.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
        <li><image src="pics/paintbrush.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
        <li><image src="pics/screw.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
        <li><image src="pics/screwdriver.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
        <li><image src="pics/shovel.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
        <li><image src="pics/vest.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
        <li><image src="pics/wrench.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
        <li><image src="pics/cone.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
        <li><image src="pics/flashlight.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
</ul>
</div>
      <button id="confirm">100% Sure!!!</button>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="checkedImageContainer">
      <ul class="checkedImageList">
      </ul>                 
</div>
```

When `$(#confirmed).clicked` i want to append every li that is checked, with ONLY it's image child.

I have previous jquery that only allows a user to click 3 checkboxes...

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {

  let maxCheckedNum = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length >= 3;     
  $("input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",maxCheckedNum);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the checked checkboxes and find the sibling `img` tag's HTML and append it inside an `li` into the `ul` `checkedImageList`

```
 $(#confirmed).click(function(){
   if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 3) {
     var img;
     $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
       img = $(this).closest('li').find('img').html();
       $('#checkedImageContainer .checkedImageList').append('<li>'+img+'</li>'); 
     });
     $('#checkedImageContainer').removeClass('hidden');
   }
   else {
     //validation for clicking atleast three images
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

On the button click, get the list of all input checkboxes with that name  and then loop it to get the src of the sibling image..

```
$('#btnAppend').click(function() {

  $("input[name='tool']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#secondList').append('<li><img src="' + $(this).parent('li').find('img').attr('src') + '"></li>');
    }
  });
});
```

Check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/z1ko8xL2/

Answer (score 0):

Just clone the `li` and remove `input` element and `append`:

```js
$('#confirm').click(function() {
  if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 3) {
    $("#imageNinpputList li input").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var li = $(this).parent().clone();
        li.find('input').remove();
        $('#checkedImageContainer ul').append(li);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('Select 3 images !')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="imageNinpputList">
  <li> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
  <li> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
  <li> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
  <li> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
  <li> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
  <li> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
    <li> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
  <li> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
  <li> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25"><input type="checkbox" name="tool"></li>
</ul>
<div>
  <button id="confirm">100% Sure!!!</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hidden" id="checkedImageContainer">
  <ul class="checkedImageList">
  </ul>
</div>
```